# What's the difference between device file and its raw version?

Tags: command-line

It's convenient to use `dd` to write image file to USB sticks. But I find sometimes people write `dd of=/dev/disk1` and there is alos `dd of=/dev/rdisk1`.

e.g.

- [The arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/USB_Installation_Media#On_Mac_OS_X)

`dd if=image.iso of=/dev/disk1 bs=8192`

- [The Raspberry Pi instruction](http://elinux.org/RPi_Easy_SD_Card_Setup#Copying_an_image_to_the_SD_card_in_Mac.C2.A0OS.C2.A0X_.28command_line.29)

`sudo dd bs=1m if=~/Downloads/2012-10-28-wheezy-raspbian/2012-10-28-wheezy-raspbian.img of=/dev/rdisk3`

What is the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On OS X, the `r` means raw device (same as on other UNIX) and on OS X the raw file is a character based I/O and the normal diskX... is a block special device.

Both of these entry points allow a program to access a bare stream of information on the drive without interacting with the filesystem (file names, paths, etc..) and the character device bypasses any buffers (that both speed up access and slow it down depending if you are making large or small operations).

Wiki has a nice article on these general concepts: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_file

Comment: nice explanation